# como pegar valor do banco em um if usando php

Tags: php, if

gente eu tenho uma tabela usuario que tem um campo categoria que é um campo boolean, em certo momento no meu codigo eu preciso que somente se categoria for true eu mostre uma opção no meu menu, mas não sei como colocar 
isso no if, alguém pode me auxiliar, estou tentando assim mas não ta dando certo:

```
<?php if((['usuario']['categoria']) == "true") {?>
<li id="users">


</li>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Ta faltando uma variável ai `['usuario']['categoria']`  pode ser um array ... se quiser comparar um booleano pode simplicar ainda.

Comment: Não seria a mesma pergunta que esta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/200779/como-bloquear-funcionalidades-dependendo-do-usuario?

Comment: coloquei uma variavel, mas agora acho que o if não ta certo porque ele ta funcionando mas mesmo qnd categoria é false ele ta considerando true kk tem algo errado

Comment: Faça `var_dump` da sua variável e poste aqui o resultado, por favor.

Comment: ta retornando NULL ...

Comment: Então sua variável está errada. Como está definindo-a?

Comment: Essa coluna é int ou varchar no banco?

Comment: entao eu criei a variavel.. ta assim agora o if.... <?php if(($CadastrarUsuario['usuarios']['categoria'])) {?>

Comment: eu defini a variavel assim $this->set('CadastrarUsuario');

Comment: eu n estou sabendo passar o valor do campo categoria para a variavel

Answer (score 1):

Da forma como está o  if a comparação é feita entre um array vazio e um booleano aquele `"true`" é convertido não por causa do true em sim mas devido a existencia de algum conteúdo. Um exemplo interessante:

```
var_dump(false == "false"); //false.
```

Para solucionar seu problema, o primeiro passo é adicionar a variável na comparação. O segundo é simplificar a comparação o PHP faz cast (para booleano) de valores o tempo todo então para saber se algum valor é `true` basta jogar ele no if ou na expressão.

Mude:

```
<?php if((['usuario']['categoria']) == "true") {?>
```

Por algo como:

```
<?php if($registro['usuario']['categoria']) {?>
```

Comment: entaão fiz isso agora amigo, acho que o meu problema esta agora em passar o valor do campo para a variavel, <?php if(($CadastrarUsuario['usuarios']['categoria'])) {?>

Comment: declaro a variavel assim $this->set('CadastrarUsuario'); ... axo qe n estou sabendo passar o valor do campo categoria para a variavel

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem, dá pra fazer assim:

```
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT categoria FROM usuario WHERE id = 'meuUser'");
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

    if ($result["categoria"] == "true"){

        echo "<li id='users'>

        </li>";
    }
```

Comment: As funções `mysql_*` estão obsoletas desde a versão 5.5 do PHP e foram inteiramente removidas do PHP 7, portanto não é recomendado utilizá-las atualmente. Use `mysqli_*` no lugar ou PDO.